# How to load image depending on data from mysql to android using picasso

Tags: android

i want to load image from mysql database and depending on item number 
for example i have 3 column in database which is id=1,2,3 when user click on item number 1 the app should display image which id is 1 
i do it for text and i want to do this in image
i used `picasso` for this

```
Picasso.with(SingleNewsDetails.this).load("http://giclub.esy.es/image/".get(passingitem).image).into(newspic);
```

passing item is int number which equal id my url contain 3 images
newspic is my imageview

```
 public void getData() {
        url = Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(passingitem);
        Toast.makeText(this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("allstudents");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                String id = respons.getString("id");
                                String address = respons.getString("address");
                                String image = respons.getString("image");
                                String desc = respons.getString("desc");
                                newsaddreess.setText(address);
                                newsdetails.setText(desc);
                                Picasso.with(SingleNewsDetails.this).load("http://giclub.esy.es/image/".get(passingitem).image).into(newspic);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
            }
        }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

}
```

json url in config

```
 public static final String DATA_URL = "http://giclub.esy.es/News.php?id=";
```

how can i do this ? sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

You should use your url value in picasso

```
url = Config.DATA_URL + String.valueOf(passingitem);
Picasso.with(SingleNewsDetails.this).load(url).into(newspic);
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.amr.fujeraapp, PID: 10588
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                      at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
                      at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                      at com.example.amr.fujeraapp.News.SingleNewsDetails$1.onResponse(SingleNewsDetails.java:69)
                      at

Comment: have you defined "newspic" in your code. it should be an imageview

Comment: ImageView newspic;
 newspic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image_news);
non is displayed and error is disappear .. there's another message

Comment: D/ViewGroup: addInArray been called, this = android.widget.ListView{42953b28 VFED.VC. .F....ID 0,20-600,951 #7f0e00bc app:id/newslist}call stack =
             java.lang.Throwable: addInArray
                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3786)
                 at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3740)
                 at